# Multiple mysql inserts from one Form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to be able to track prescribed medications taken on a daily basis. I am not sure if how I’m trying to do this is the right strategy, as I’m just learning. The strategy I’m currently using is to use one table to track each prescribed item by date and using a foreign key to the prescribed items details in a second table.

My immediate question is it possible to some how group each prescribed item on a single form to collect the taken amounts and then insert each into mysql?

This is what I have so far. This works fine for just one item, but I want to have multiple items for each date. Is it possible to  have multiple groups of inputs on a page to create multiple inserts? Maybe my strategy is all wrong. Is this possible or is another strategy necessary?

```
<form method="post" action="db_insert.php">
    <?php
        $date = "2016-15-16";
    ?>
    <?php echo "Date " . $date; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="prescribedid" value="1"><br>
    Prescribed #1 Amount: 200 <input type="checkbox" name="taken_amount" value="200">
    Prescribed #1 Units: mg <input type="checkbox" name="units" value="mg">
    Prescribed #1 Frequency: daily <input type="checkbox" name="frequency" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="prescribedid" value="2"><br>
    Prescribed #2 Amount: 200 <input type="checkbox" name="taken_amount" value="200">
    Prescribed #2 Units: mg <input type="checkbox" name="units" value="mg">
    Prescribed #2 Frequency: daily <input type="checkbox" name="frequency" value="1"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit"> 
    </form>
```

db_insert.php

```
<?php
$date = "2016-08-15";
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));

echo $date . "<br>";

$prescribedid = $_POST["prescribedid"];
$taken_amount = $_POST["taken_amount"];
$units        = $_POST["units"];
$frequency    = $_POST["frequency"];

// 1st Insert
$query[] = "INSERT INTO `tracked_db` (`takenid`, `date`, `prescribedid`, `taken_amount`, `taken_units`, `frequency`)";
$query .= " VALUES (NULL, '{$date}', '${prescribedid}', '{$taken_amount}', '{$units}', '{$frequency}')";

// 2nd insert
$query[] = "INSERT INTO `tracked_db` (`takenid`, `date`, `prescribedid`, `taken_amount`, `taken_units`, `frequency`)";
$query .= " VALUES (NULL, '{$date}', '${prescribedid}', '{$taken_amount}', '{$units}', '{$frequency}')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
```

foreach the queries to insert.

Comment: `$query[] =` means it's an array, but `$query .=` means it's a string.

Comment: Didn't you say _This works fine for just one item_ If it actually does, then this is not the code you are actually running. Post the real code

Comment: You are correct. I tried to make my question clearer and modified my code. The first $query is not an Array and should just be $query. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit multiple input with same name then you have to give name of the `inputs` with `[]`.
Eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="taken_amount[]" value="200">
```

And in the server side, they will be received or treated as array.

Eg: Here `$taken_amount = $_POST["taken_amount"];` `$taken_amount` is an array containing values of all `inputs` with the name `taken_amount`. Then you can iterate through this array to retrieve the value.

In your case iterate through any of your parameters and append/concatenate the `$query` so all the rows can be inserted at once.

Eg:

```
$query='';
for($i=0;$i<count($taken_amount);$i++){
    $query .= "INSERT INTO `tracked_db` (`takenid`, `date`, `prescribedid`,   `taken_amount`, `taken_units`, `frequency`)
              " VALUES(NULL, '{$date}', '{$prescribedid[$i]}', '{$taken_amount[$i]}', '{$units[$i]}', '{$frequency[$i]}')";
}
```

Comment: You need to elaborate on how to uses this in the PHP script.

Comment: You might want to check the syntax of a `foreach` or the `for` or both before that gets a DV

Comment: Thank you!! This works. I looked at the name="taken_amount"=[] construct before, but didn't see how it would work. Your example cleared it up for me. I did change the variables in the INSERT to {$_POST['taken_amount'][$i]}' to get the actual $_POST value.

Answer (score 0):

Those hidden inputs are useless. You need to designate your form fields individually, not try to group them under a hidden field. Start here:

```
<form method="post" action="db_insert.php">
<?php
    $date = "2016-15-16";
?>
<?php echo "Date " . $date; ?>
   <br>
    Prescribed #1 Amount: 200 <input type="checkbox" name="p1taken_amount" value="200">
Prescribed #1 Units: mg <input type="checkbox" name="p1units" value="mg">
Prescribed #1 Frequency: daily <input type="checkbox" name="p1frequency" value="1">
 <br>
Prescribed #2 Amount: 200 <input type="checkbox" name="p2taken_amount" value="200">
Prescribed #2 Units: mg <input type="checkbox" name="p2units" value="mg">
Prescribed #2 Frequency: daily <input type="checkbox" name="p2frequency" value="1"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit"> 
</form>
```